# Convert RTP Payload (payload type 107, AMR-WB 16khz 1Channel) to .wav

Tags: python-3.x, wav, scapy, converters, amr

I'm working in Python 3.6 under Linux Ubuntu and I used the Scapy lib to extract data from a bin file which contained the following stack: IP/UDP/RTP. The RTP-PAYLOAD TYPE is 107 (dynamic), a=rtpmap:107 AMR-WB/16000/1.

I put it into a file in raw format and I called it ***src.aud***, but it also wouldn't be a problem to put write it in hex. Now what do I have to do exactly to transform it into audio data format like .wav or .mp3 for example, which is on every computer?

I've already made an' effort with this file:

```
https://gist.github.com/ollyja/5fe34ba997d8fa8a3f6ff4fb883feca2
```

But there is a dependency on SILK audio decoder.

```
https://github.com/gaozehua/SILKCodec
```

But that's all written in C and I don't understand how to use it in my environment. Isn't there a simplier way or do I miss s.th. ?

Thanks for Your help

Comment: Playing around with audio format will likely require to use a library. If the format is too uncommon, you might end up depending on C libraries or ffmpeg... your current code honnestly looks not bad (even though the best option would probably be to find a python library or a ffmpeg python interface)

Comment: @Cukic0d I've found a way and I thought that eventually it could interest You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document RFC4867 (can easily found with google), chapters 4.3, 4.4 and 5. First it must be found out, if the RTP-PAYLOAD is bandwidth efficient (chapter 4.3) or octet aligned (4.4). In this case it's bandwidth efficient according 4.3.4. and it must be transformed according chapter 5, 5.1 and 5.3 before writing it into a file.amr or file.awb (both works).

The resulting file can be listened to with VLC-Media player and with 'Videos' of Linux Ubuntu. But it can also be converted into all kinds of audiofiles by the online-converter 'convertio'.

```
https://convertio.co/it/
```

A direct way to do that in Python is the Python library ffmpy that has FFmpeg wrapped.

```
https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
```

Under Quickstart there is an' example that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a AMR decoder(ffmpeg - libavcodec) to decode the AMR payload data.

AMR decoder will give you PCM data, which can be written to a wav file (16 KHz).

AMR codec library can be used with ctypes python interface - Extending Python With C Libraries.

Comment: Which library do You advise me ?

Comment: you can use the ffmpeg amr wb codec , as part of the libavcodec library