# How to write to an AMR-WB file in multichannel mode with Python under linux from RTP PAYLOAD

Tags: rtp, amr, avaudiofile

I've successfully written the RTP-payload into an amr-file and it works fine, according to the answer written in this question.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961965/convert-rtp-payload-payload-type-107-amr-wb-16khz-1channel-to-wav
```

Now I tried to write a multichannel file according to chapter 5.2 according to document RFC 4867, but I failed. No decoder accepts the file. I've got 2 channels (stereo).

I've already checked the correctness of the voice data in the file. And they seem correct.
First I put the header according to chapter 5.2:

```
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867#section-5.2
```

The magic number I checked and it's correct. Then I add the chan-desc-field and it should be as far as I understood:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```

In the audiofile I read the same values. Is this correct?
The audiodata is saved according to 5.3 (1st paragraph):

```
1.pack_chan1 1.pack_chan2, 2.pack_chan1 2.pack_chan2, etc
```

Now clicking on the amr-file (or awb), the decoder says, that an error has occurred.
On the contrary, when I just write one channel in a file, according
to chapter 5.1 and 5.3, everything works fine. It can be played with windows VLC-MEDIA PLAYER and
Linux Ubuntu's Videos.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks and regards

**Update:**
Chapter 3.5 of [RFC4867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867#section-3.5), second paragraph says, that usually, codecs *do not support encoding of
multi-channel audio content into a single bitstream, they can be
used to separately encode and decode each of the individual channels.*

So what can I do to produce the stereo sound with the 2 channels?

Comment: check if it is a amr file header issue or amr data  issue.

Comment: @mail2subhajit It should be a file header issue, because I've done the following: I put exactly the same data of one channel in both channels. This data was already working in 1-channel mode, so it cannot be wrong. At this point the only issue that remains is the file header ones. If You look in the documentation RFC4867, which link I have posted, I cannot understand where I was wrong.

Comment: you can check the error logs of the VLC player, when you are trying to play the .amr file. it should give you some clue.

Comment: @mail2subhajit I've found some hint in the document RFC4867, chapter 3.5, second paragraph. It says: "Although AMR and AMR-WB codecs themselves do not support encoding of multi-channel audio content into a single bit stream, they can be used to separately encode and decode each of the individual channels". So this would mean that theoretically the file could be ok?

Comment: @mail2subhajit Ok, now I've done so. It says: _**avcodec debug**: detected format: amr
**avcodec error**: Could not open C:\Users\Operatore\Documents\stereo.amr: **Operation not permitted**_. In the single channel version, which is working, it says: _**avcodec debug**: detected format: amr
**main debug**: selecting program id=0
**avcodec debug**: adding es: audio codec = sawb (73729)
**avcodec debug**: AVFormat(ffmpeg Lavf58.3.100) supported stream
**avcodec debug**: - format = amr (3GPP AMR)_

Comment: @mail2subhajit : Here are the links to the log-files: Stereo 2channels (not working) [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neByCO5cDILB3JgbFI4V9Qwfykov6e8h/view) and the Single Channel decoding VLC logfile (working): [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qzSyyqwRzw0aIY3p4rLwtX-DFJMoZRH_/view?usp=sharing) . Interesting lines: 79+. If You had some idea it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mail2subhajit: ..and here are the 2 logs from the attempt with ffmpy that wraps ffmpeg in linux: Successful monochannel: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pJg6zOnpPAvW1kzRzUCAsdqbN7t1B2ng/view?usp=sharing) , failed bichannel converting: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QS83QjIlDI9IEuVLA3-vbNtHE_XGvO8u/view?usp=sharing) . Even with the help of the logs I cannot be sure if the problem is the file-header of the data. Have You got an' idea? Thanks.

Comment: from these logs I can see - "Operation not permitted " which is hard to understand.

Comment: Can you covert a stereo wav file to amr file through ffmpeg cmdline and play this amr file to check the logs and compare the header data. hope it helps.